# What are ideal hooks to call register_sidebars?

Tags: plugins, hooks, register-sidebar

Where should a plugin ideally hook to call `register_sidebar();`?

Will `init` do just fine?

```
function my_plugin_register_sidebars() {
    $args = array(
        'name' => 'foo'
        'description' => 'bar'
        ...
    );
    register_sidebar( $args );
}
add_action( '**????**', 'my_plugin_register_sidebar' );
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Twenty Eleven and Twenty Twelve use the `widgets_init` action. Given that these themes are generally considered to use best practices for theme development, I think this hook would be ideal.

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'init', 'my_plugin_register_sidebar' );
```

Edit: @Brasofilo - the init is used to register menus, I figured it could also be used to register other stuff. I could be wrong though since I don't develop themes. An explanation of why using "init" is wrong would help me in the future. http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus

Comment: Can you give a reference for using this hook? The Codex points to [this article](http://justintadlock.com/archives/2010/11/08/sidebars-in-wordpress) that indicates `widgets_init`...